# How to handle composite type in a template class

Tags: c++, templates, initialization

I have the following template class definition:  a typical Matrix class -

```
    template<typename T>
    class Matrix
    {
        std::vector<Array<T>> m_rows;
        uint32_t m_M;
        uint32_t m_N;
        bool m_container;

    public:

        Matrix() : m_rows{}, m_M(0), m_N(0), m_container(true) { }

        Matrix(uint32_t width, uint32_t height, T val, uint32_t strideX=0, uint32_t strideY=0) :
            m_rows(std::max(strideY, height), Array<T>(width, T{}, strideX)),
            m_M(width), m_N(height), m_container(false)
        {
            for(uint32_t row=0; row < height; row++)
            {
                m_rows[row] = val;
            }
        }
//more class methods, not relevant to this discussion
```

Code in main():

```
int main()
{
     typedef struct { float a; float b; } MyStruct;

     MyStruct val = { 1.0, 2.0 };
     Matrix<MyStruct> m(3,3,val);  //so, define a 3x3 matrix with 'val' struct as constant value
}
```

The Matrix will try to initialize the std::vector<> container with T{} entries.

To my surprise, this worked!  So, my next question is, WHY does T{} work?  Is this the C++ way to 'cast' literals to the 'T' type, even if 'T' is composite?

thanks, Charles

Comment: Because the `T` in this case is `MyStruct`. Since `MyStruct{}` compiles, `T{}` will compile as well. Technically, `MyStruct` is an *aggregate* type here.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using `MyStruct` only. Since `MyStruct` can be initialized with `{}`, it can be compiled.

But if you have other classes that cannot be initialized with a default constructor, it can't be compiled.

```
struct foo{};

class faa{
public:
    fee(int x){}
};
```

In this case,

```
Matrix<foo>
```

can be compiled, while

```
Matrix<faa>
```

cannot.